# Update using addToSet adding in the same duplication in meteor and mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Update using addToSet adding in the same duplication in meteor and mongoDB.

My update function

```
let data = Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {
    $addToSet: {
        "course_teach_list": {
            "course_id": courseId,
            "class_id_list": [],
        }
    }}
)
```

First update:

```
  "course_teach_list": [
    {
      "course_id": "qziRfZ8GFEW7j3QhL",
      "class_id_list": []
    },
  ]
```

Second update into class_id_list:

```
  "course_teach_list": [
    {
      "course_id": "qziRfZ8GFEW7j3QhL",
      "class_id_list": [
        "zx9ir93epdddricRM"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Third update which has a duplication "course_id": "qziRfZ8GFEW7j3QhL". how do I prevent this? I think its because class_id_list is not empty anymore and its not the same, thats why it update a duplicate

```
  "course_teach_list": [
    {
      "course_id": "qziRfZ8GFEW7j3QhL",
      "class_id_list": [
        "zx9ir93epdddricRM"
      ]
    },
    {
      "course_id": "qziRfZ8GFEW7j3QhL",<--duplication! should not update!
      "class_id_list": []
    }
  ]
```

Comment: What do you want your document to look like after the three addToSets?

Comment: for the 3rd update it shouldnt go update because its a duplication. same course_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `update` add one 'duplicate' `class_id_list`, because `class_id_list` is different.

You could restrict `update` with a query object that prevents the update if the `course_id` is already present in `course_teach_list`. sample codes as below,

```
let data = Meteor.users.update(
    {_id: Meteor.userId(), 'course_teach_list.course_id': {$ne: courseId}},
    {$addToSet: {
        "course_teach_list": {
            "course_id": courseId,
            "class_id_list": [],
        }
    }}
)
```